# No audio with a MS Lifecam Cinema

Tags: 12.10, sound, webcam

I searched the forum and web to no avail. I am running Ubuntu 12.10 and am trying to get a Microsoft Lifecam Cinema setup. The video was plug-and-play but no joy with the audio. I have used alsamixer and confirmed all settings.

The mic is unmuted and I have adjusted the capture volume level. What am I missing. I have been successfully using a Logitech cam with no issues at all, but my Lifecam's video quality is much better.

Any help is much appreciated...

Answer (score 0):

[This](http://www.ideasonboard.org/uvc/#footnote-13) might be the reason of the issue you're experiencing:

Despite being able to work with lower USB bandwidths, **this device always requests the maximum possible bandwidth**, even for the MJPEG format. **Using one of those cameras in conjunction with another USB device (including the camera internal microphone) will likely fail**. You can tell the uvcvideo driver to estimate the required bandwidth instead of trusting the camera by setting the FIX_BANDWIDTH quirk. This will only affect uncompressed formats, and even there there's no guarantee of success. See the FAQ for more information.